# Open all files in a folder using notepad++

Tags: file, notepad++

I have to make a minor change in all the html files of my site. The files are stored in structure which is as below,

```
/Site
--2012
  --Jan
    --File1.html
    --File2.html
    --File3.html
    --File3.html
  --Feb
    --File1.html
    --File2.html
```

And so on..

There are files from 2006 stored in a similar fashion. Opening each of them manually is time consuming as there are hundreds of files.

Is there a easier way to do this using notepad++?

Comment: dont work with dirs. You can try to mark/select all HTML-Files and open it with N++.

Comment: How do I mark files ? I'm guessing even to do that I'll have to manually go to each folder and mark ?

Comment: Using windows - Uhm yeah, N++ is only for Win. Using the Mouse and select all Files. Additional you can hold the **STRG** Key to select more that one file.

Comment: The suggestion by Jordan below worked. Anyways thanks for you time, appreciate it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just simply drag the folder containing your site files into notepad++. It opens all files(I assume it just opens txt,html, and other compatible files) including ones in sub directories.

Alternatively, if you want to do them one month at a time you could do File>Open and then shift+click from the top to the bottom to select as many files as you want.

Or just use a better text editor like sublime text where you can just open entire folders

Comment: The dragging option worked !! It opened everything including image files, but its good enough for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: didn't work for me. I have a lot of files in my project which are in multiple subfolders.

Comment: Not handy to open all files when you have a big project. In that case, I would rather use SadiQ's answer.

Comment: Opens a special window with a tree hierarchy instead of opening all but still lets me do a search on all via the context menu, so it does what I wanted initially.

Answer (score 23):

Click on View -> Project Panel 1

Only if there's nothing in the panel click on Workspace -> New Workspace

Otherwise click on Workspace -> Add New Project

Click on Project Name and click on Edit -> Add Files from directory.

Works with Notepad++ ver. 6.7.4

Comment: This is the one I was looking for, kinda similar to sublimetext's workspace and project / open folder.

Comment: I was looking for that functionality too... I didn't know N++ had it and it seems I wasn't looking in the right places. Thanks @SadiQ ! ;)

Answer (score 4):

This is the easiest solution I found:

1. Have a Notepad++ program shortcut file on your Desktop.
2. Drag the folder from File Explorer to the Notepad++ shortcut.

Remark: just Drap and Drop a folder into Notepad++ program in the latest version (as of 6.9.1) will trigger "Open folder as workspace" instead of opening all files.

Answer (score 3):

While you might want to open all files as a workspace I did actually want to open every single file. Drag and dropping a folder resulted in that folder being set as the current workspace folder. To instead open those files I did need to check the `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Default Directory` > `Open all files of folder instead of launching Folder as Workspace on folder dropping`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop your folder into Notepad ++ and it will open each files recursively.

Answer (score 1):

at the menu bar select: view-> folder as workplace. and then you can search the folder you want

Answer (score 1):

go to properties of soft. right click on shortcut or icon, then change mod to run this soft like if useing windows 8 or 10 set comtapility mode on windows 7 and it will opens all files, in folders u dragged

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to replace text, you can also use the Find In Files tab.

1. Open the interface using CTRL+H,
2. Select the *Find in Files* tab,
3. Enter the find and replace phrases,
4. Add a filter to select only those files you need: File*.html could work in your case,
5. Select the top most directory that contains the files you want to replace text in,
6. Make sure you select the option: *In all sub-folders*,
7. Double check or use *Find All* to check the search results,
8. Hit *Replace in Files*.

Answer (score 0):

To open complete project folders & files you have to follow few steps:

Open Notepad++ then 
step 1: go to **view and find project panel**. In that choose **project panel 1**.
step 2: Now left side you can see **"Workspacename"** and right side **"new 1"** text. 
step 3: Now you have to **go to File -> Open Folder as Workspace** and **choose the project location and press "Select Folder".**
step 4: now complete project will be shown in **workspace (left side)**.